# android. display the number of asterisks more than the password is

Tags: android

the following logic:

1. user enters password
2. login is successful
3. user logouts

as result no matter what password was entered some stable count of asterisks is displayed (number of the shown asterisks should be different than the password is).

**example:**

user enters password `123`. login is sucessful. then he logouts. as result password is shown like `*****` (count of the asterisks is bigger than the password is)

Is that possible?

Maybe I can use `ReplacementTransformationMethod`, but I cannot find how to use it correctly.

Comment: Please be clear. Do you want to show some fixed `n` number of asterisk in password edittext after user logouts? Or you want to show `n` number of asterisks where n is calculated based on password length user entered in last login?

Comment: I want to use some fixed number of asterisks no matter what password was entered

Comment: Then why don't you just use `your_editText.setText("********");`?